# How to write a script to get total record count on filemaker

Tags: filemaker

Hi I am very new to filemaker pro and instead of making a report, is there a way I can write a script that counts total number of records recorded on my filemaker database?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A script with the following script steps should work:

```
Go to Layout [layout that displays the table with the records you'd like to count]
Show All Records
Set Variable [$count; Get ( FoundCount )]
```

Answer (score 1):

> is there a way I can write a script that counts total number of
>   records recorded on my filemaker database?

Assuming you mean "the total number of records *in the current table*", you can use the `Get(TotalRecordCount)` function. No script is necessary for this.

Note the difference between this function and  the `Get(FoundCount)` function that returns the number of records *in the current found set*.

--
P.S. If using these functions in a calculation field, make sure it is set to "Do not store calculation results..." under Storage Options.